# How to use a customized AppBar

Tags: android, material-design

I would like to get an effect as the one shown on the picture (extracted from some application that uses it): an AppBar that holds a custom layout.

[image]

How could this be achieved? can it be done with a customization of the AppBar? or should I use a regulalr layout simulating being an AppBar?

Thank you!

Comment: can u tried for this layout ?

Comment: You need to create custom toolbar with text shown as EUR and other text and use recycler view

Comment: But how can inject any layout in the toolbar?

Comment: @edutesoy toolbar it's just a view group. Like LinearLayour or other. Just put your stuff inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- This is a centered logo -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <!-- This is a centered title -->
        <!--
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
            />
            -->

        <!-- This is a custom left side button -->
        <!--
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton" />
            -->

        <!-- This is a custom right side button -->
        <!--
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_search"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_magnify_white_24dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton" />
            -->

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Custom Toolbar and call this layout in main layout.Can use any layout inside it

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use Whatever Layout You Desire As normally you do everywhere, The Structure Example below can be a good Guide:

```js
< android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  ... >


  <DrawerLayout >
  ...
  </DrawerLayout>


     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     ... >

       <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
       ... >


         <FrameLayout
         ... >
         // ---- WHATEVER LAYOUT YOU WANT

         </FrameLayout>

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         .../ >

         <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
         .../>

       </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
  ... />

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  .../>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Note: The FrameLayout I put in the code, Literally Can be Anything, A RelativeLayout, A LinearLayout, etc...